# Creating filenames using variable output in Fortran 90

Tags: fortran

I am trying to generate an alphanumeric file name.

Where the first part is an alphabet and the second part is an integer of length 5(eg. P41608.txt). The integer is already stored in a variable 'station' which is an array(size=74).
I am trying to create the file using the syntax

`pfile='P' // 'station(1).txt' where station(1)=41608`

When I print the 'pfile' output, it is displayed as 'Pstation(1).txt'. I also tried to separate '.txt' using '//', but got the same output. Is there any way, one can use the variable output in a file name?

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. This has been asked many many times before, have you searched at all?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Please someone retag it. I would have done that if I knew you were around.